# $.ajax to call post rest service

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui

ajax code used to call rest service

```
   $
.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url : 'http://service/status',
    success : function(dt) {
                    $.each(dt, function(key, val) {
            var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
            $.each(val, function(k, v) {
                $('<td>' + v + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
            });
            tr.appendTo("#tableID");
        });

    },
    error : function(msg) {
        alert(msg.responseText);
    }

});
```

i want to sent json data in request body can you please help me out on what to add in above code

Comment: You want to send JSON data in a header, or in the post body? Does this REST service live on the same domain as your script above?

Comment: $.ajax({ type : "post", url : 'http://service/status', headers: {'key': jsonvalue}, //etc.

Comment: I want it tyo send in request body not in request header

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to add something to the request headers then you'll need to use the "headers" option or the "beforeSend" event that jQuery exposes.  See the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I'm guessing that what you really want is to add data to the body of the request and you can do that using the "data" parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url : 'http://service/status',
    data : {
        your: 'data here',
        someJSON: '{"foo":"bar","boo":"far"}'
    },
    success : function(dt) {
                    $.each(dt, function(key, val) {
            var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
            $.each(val, function(k, v) {
                $('<td>' + v + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
            });
            tr.appendTo("#tableID");
        });

    },
    error : function(msg) {
        alert(msg.responseText);
    }

});
```

If I'm mistaken and you really do want headers, then simply replace "data" with "headers" and you are good to go...

Comment: But I want the data to be passed in request body not in request header

Comment: That was what I assumed, and that is what this code does.  Anything you put in that "data" property will be available as part of the POST body.

Comment: {
   "userId" : 12256, 
   "start" : "2012-03-15",
    "end" : "2012-03-15",
    "Id" : 97050
     }                                                                                                                                        is the data in correct order let me know if something is wrong